# Create User Groups In Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a research app which uses Firebase Authenticiation. As any research goes, some of the app users will be in the expiremental group and the others will be in the control group. I am wondering how I can register this with firebase, as the app functionality for the experimental group will be slightly different than that for the control group.

Comment: This is far to broad a question to be answered but a starting point would be to store what kind of users your app has; this would be done through a Firebase /users/ node where each user has a type associated with it. */users/uid_0/type: exp_group* and */users/uid_1/type : control_group*

Comment: Try looking into using custom user claims: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims